# Extract file name from json using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, json

I have a big json file and and i am trying to extract the names of the files from it using AngularJS. How can i extract the file names using ng-repeat for each year? Here is my simple example in [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/yLIlWEQCByjkW9sQNYi4?p=preview)

```
  App.controller('TodoCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('data.json')
       .then(function(res){
          $scope.todos = res.data;                
        });
  });
```

I am not sure how to create this controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just access items through the key's value,

```
App.controller('TodoCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('data.json')
       .then(function(res){
          $scope.todos = res.data[2015];           
        });
});
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/AeHYQOP8hNXzIV0oEuFD)**

Answer (score 0):

You can access them as (key,value) pair.

**HTML**

```
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(year,files) in todos" ng-click="sendData(year,files)">
      {{year}}:{{files}} --- click here
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Have a look at [DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/HUBhzzsU5AauG51ZfBB4?p=preview)